# DFP sizeMapping Breaks Sponsorships

Tags: responsive-design, google-dfp

In my experiences so far, sizeMapping(), for responsive ads in DFP breaks sponsorships.

For example, if I define a sizeMapping like so:

```
addSize([1024, 768], [970, 90], [728, 90], [320, 50], [300, 250])
```

Then I setup a sponsorship on a particular ad unit that's a 728x90. 
I also setup a Run of Site (placement) 970x90 that includes all ad units, including the sponsored one, at a lower priority.

The result is that the 970x90 will show before the sponsored 728x90 because of the sizeMapping variable, even on the ad units that are specifically sponsored by the 728x90.

Help!?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this? you need to use `defineSizeMapping` instead of `addSize`.

So it should be something like:

```
googletag
    .defineSlot('AD_UNIT_PATH', [0, 0], 'ID')
    .defineSizeMapping([[1024, 768], [[970, 90], [728, 90], [320, 50], [300, 250]]])
    // Assuming [1024, 768] is the VP size & [[970, 90], [728, 90], [320, 50], [300, 250]] are the creative sizes.
    .addService(window.googletag.pubads());
```

Comment: We moved away from DFP, so it's no longer a problem :)